# Trying to install DB_File in Strawberry Perl following instructions

Tags: perl

I'm trying to install [`DB_File`](https://metacpan.org/module/DB_File) in Strawberry Perl following [these instructions](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Install_DB_File_on_Strawberry_Perl).

- Download and install the Oracle/Sleepycat libdb MSI from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/berkeley-db/htdocs/popup/db/4.6.21/db-msi.html)
- Go to the Berkeley DB directory - e.g. C:\Program Files\Oracle\Berkeley DB 4.6.21
- Copy the include directory to \strawberry\c\include\db:
- Copy the lib\libdb46.lib file to \strawberry\c\lib\libdb.a:
- Comment out two typedefs in \strawberry\c\include\db\db.h

But I can't find the folder **db**, also file **db\db.h** and folder **libdb.a**. Please help me to install `DB_File` in Perl.

I use Windows 7 and Strawberry Perl 5.14.2.1/64bit

Thank you all.

Comment: I use Windows 7 and Strawberry Perl 5.14.2.1/64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB_File module is already preinstalled in strawberry perl 5.14.x

If you want to install/upgrade newer version from CPAN you do not need to install DB library as all required devel files (*.h + *.a) are also included in strawberry perl 5.14.x - simply run:

```
cpan -i DB_File
```

--
kmx

Answer (score 0):

The intention of the writer is that the *entire directory* `C:\Program Files\Oracle\Berkeley DB 4.6.21\include` (or the equivalent on your system) should be copied into the `C:\strawberry\c\include` directory (making `C:\strawberry\c\include\include`) and then renamed to `db`.

`db.h` is a file in the new `C:\strawberry\c\include\db` directory. You need to edit it as described.

`libd.a` is a *file*, that the instructions tell you to copy from `libdb46.lib` in `C:\Program Files\Oracle\Berkeley DB 4.6.21\lib`. (These days it is more likely to be around `libdb53.lib`.) You should *copy* this file to the `C:\strawberry\c\lib` directory and rename it to `libdb.a`.

After that you need to edit the `config.in` file in the `DB_File` distribution directory as the instructions describe. Then just build, test and install as normal.